# Implementing copy\move operator= for classes with const members

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Imagine simple class something like this:

```
struct A {
    void* const memory;
    int const size;
}
```

Implementation of copy and move constructors are really trivial, but I am not able to grasp, how to implement move and copy operators. I've tried to do copy-and-swap, but it requires overload of `std::swap` and I was not able to invent it, since I am not able to change const variables. Is making my class members non-const is the only way?

Comment: You can't really modify or move const things.

Comment: What exactly would copying a `void* const` mean? Do you want to copy the pointer or the object it points to?

Comment: @NicolBolas deep copy

Comment: @Starl1ght: A deep copy of what? It's a ***void*** pointer; it could point to anything.